# How can I kill fullscreen procces? (Cursor moves, tty doesn't open)

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, games, freeze

after starting the game (DotA), the game freezes, but the cursor moves, the multimedia buttons work. but no keyboard shortcuts allow you to open the terminal, minimize the game or do anything else. I tried cttl-alt-F(1-9),ctrl-alt-backspace, ctrl-al-t, in doesn't work. But I see my PC is working and I believe there is an issue to kill the game process or minimize it. Is there any other keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: My OS Kubuntu 22.04

Comment: Did you tried [SUPER](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/keyboard-key-super.html.en) + D ?